# Application.SheetFollowHyperlink Event Mac: Office 2011

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I cannot get the `Application.SheetFollowHyperlink` event work on Excel 2011.

I have a two workbooks with over forty worksheets in each.

I would like to be able to trap the clicking of the hyperlinks on the application level (not worksheet level) If possible, I want to write a macro that gets called whenever a hyperlink is clicked anywhere on any workbook.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This works at the Workbook level:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://google.com"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the perfect workaround and deserves to be accepted as the answer. Thanks Paul.

Comment: Thanks @smozgur - I'm glad it helped